# How to create a matrix from a quarter matrix using symmetry

Tags: matlab, matrix, symmetry

As an instance I have a matrix like this:

```
A = [1 2;
     3 4]
```

The matrix A is the quarter of a matrix, the full matrix B can be obtained by mirroring A on the vertical and horizontal mirror axes. The resullt should be:

```
B =     [1 2 2 1;
         3 4 4 3;
         3 4 4 3;
         1 2 2 1]
```

How can I achive this in Matlab?

Edit: Is there a better way than

```
Q = [A fliplr(A)]
B = [Q ; flip(Q)]
```

?

Comment: Your edit actually looks like the best option to me. Quick and easily understood

Comment: Thanks, then I do it this way.

Comment: This might be a cool [codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) problem as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it in a single line, although "better" is slightly subjective

```
B = [A, fliplr(A); flipud(A), rot90(A,2)]
```

Comment: Even better, since you don't create the intermediate variable